# Not able to access application running on kubernetes pod (Using Docker-Desktop: Single-node cluster)

Tags: kubernetes

See below service is running:

[image]

and Below error i am getting while trying to access it:

[image]

Kubectl get pods:

[image]

Yaml files:

1. Service:
   [image]
2. Deployment:

   [image]

Comment: How about your pods? Did you test the service directly in the pods? You could use `dnsutil` to test intra-cluster. See [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#create-a-simple-pod-to-use-as-a-test-environment) link. Please post the output of the command: `kubectl get pods` and the yaml file of pods and service.

Comment: Edited my post given you the yaml files and kubectl get pods output. I am not sure what i am missing here, it should be accessible from my host machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check pod status if it's running or not.

Also, you can try with `port-forwarding` to POD

`kubectl port-forward <POD name> 8086:8086` & open `localhost:8086`